# Making a long image without resizing

Tags: image

I need to put many images together side by side but without changing the height or width of any of them. That is to say, it will just be one image of a constant height but very long width as the image are sitting horizontally.

I've been using Python and the PIL library but what I've tried so far is producing an image that makes all the images smaller to concatenate into one long image.

```
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 100000000  # For PIL Image error when handling very large images

imgs = [ Image.open(i) for i in list_of_images ]

widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in imgs))
total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

# Place first image
new_im.paste(imgs[0],(0,0))

# Iteratively append images in list horizontally
hoffset=0
for i in range(1,len(imgs),1):
    hoffset=imgs[i-1].size[0]+hoffset  # update offset**
    new_im.paste(imgs[i],(hoffset,0))

new_im.save('row.jpg')
```

The result I'm getting now is one image made up of concatenated images in a horizontal row. This is what I want, except the images are being made smaller and smaller in the concatenation process. I want the end result to not make the images smaller and instead produce an image made of the input images with their original size. So the output image will just have to have a very long width.

Comment: What do you mean by the images being made smaller and smaller? I am not getting what you would like to do: do you want to do some horizontal concatenation or put the images on top of each other so that the *"background"* of the smaller images is the bigger image?

Comment: How about showing the result you get?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a bug while updating the offsets.
You should replace your iteration block with:

```
imgs = [Image.open(i) for i in list_of_images]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in imgs))

new_img = Image.new('RGB', (sum(widths), max(heights)))
h_offset = 0
for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    new_img.paste(img, (h_offset, 0))
    h_offset += img.size[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! One more thing, if I try to use a list of images that is to long it gives an operating system error, I suppose there is a limit to how many images can be put together, is there a way around this?

Comment: I am not sure. If this is a limitation of PIL / Pillow, you would need to rely on a different library (`cv`?) for the output of the image. Alternatively, if the image is not meant to be used as such, you might be better off using a NumPy array instead.

Comment: @illwill Note that the OS error may be related to something else. Perhaps, you are hitting the limit of the maximum number of files opened by a single process in your OS. Perhaps you should ask a separate question, so that you can give more details about it.

Comment: I think you can use `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None` to allow PIL unlimited image sizes. Also, you don't need to hold all the images in memory at once - you could open one, paste it into the big one and then open the next one else you effectively double the amount of memory you need by holding all images in a list and then holding them all again in the monster montage you are making.